# Disable href in inner element of div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, href

I have a question. How can i disable href from inner element of div when href is placed in the parent element? Maybe I try to visualize it:

```
<span class='img' href="someLink">
  <div class="main">
    <h2 contenteditable="true">Some txt</h2>
  </div>
</span>
```

I want to disable `href` function from `<h2>` (because I want to edit it by clicking on them, now as you know I am redirecting to href url), and left it in other html elements. How can i do that? Is there any option to do it using only html tag(s)? Or the only one option is to use js / jQuery? Can u give me an example or solution?

Comment: What does "disable href function from <h2>" mean? `href` is an attribute of  `anchor` tag. Does it even have meaning for `span`?

Comment: Why would a span have an href attribute?

Comment: maybe placing a href inside a span is not a good idea, but I just want you to imagine, that the one element is inside the other one and the href should be disable in the child element. I hope you understand. R3tep answer was perfect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this :

```
<h2 contenteditable="true" onclick='return false;'>Some txt</h2>
```

Comment: yep i just have to wait a few minutes to do it :)